# glmertree to fit logistic regression with two-column y

Tags: logistic, multilevel-analysis, glmm, rpart, party

With both glm and glmer, if I wanted to fit a proportion, I could do it as
either:

```
glm(cbind(successes, failures) ~ rest.of.model)

## or

glm(sucesses/total ~ rest.of.model, weights = total)

## where:  total <- successes + failures
```

(For my use case, I prefer the call with the two-column matrix, as I it
allows me to easily use other weights in the fit, too)

I've tried using glmertree, and none of the above two seem to work. The
first gives

```
Error in eval(family$initialize) : y values must be 0 <= y <= 1
```

The second gives a bunch of

```
Error in chol.default(meat) : 
  the leading minor of order 1 is not positive definite

and eventually fails
```

I think the problem with the two-column matrix is triggered in the very first call to `glmertree`. This calls `partykit:::glmfit` which in turn calls `stats::glm.fit`;  `glm.fit` expects, for `y`, a vector, and complains if the values of y are not in [0, 1].

I've tried to pass the data in such a way (by playing with a single column y and different ways of specifying the weights), to no avail. Maybe this is not currently possible? What would be the alternatives? (I can use a logit transformation of the response, and use `lmertree`, but that is not the same as a logistic regression).

These are a couple of examples. I've used (abused) the examples in the
vignette:

````
library(glmertree)
data("MHserviceDemo", package = "glmertree")

d1 <- MHserviceDemo

d1$y1 <- 10 * (d1$outcome - min(d1$outcome))
d1$p1 <- d1$y1/36
d1$n <- rep(36, nrow(d1))
d1$failures <- d1$n - d1$y1

## Nope: Error in eval(family$initialize) : y values must be 0 <= y <= 1
fit1 <- glmertree(cbind(y1, n - y1) ~ 1 | cluster_id |
                      age + gender + emotional + autism,
                  data = d1, family = "binomial")

## Same thing
fit1 <- glmertree(cbind(y1, failures) ~ 1 | cluster_id |
                      age + gender + emotional + autism,
                  data = d1, family = "binomial")

## Convergence and aborts
fit2 <- glmertree(p1 ~ 1 | cluster_id |
                      age + gender + emotional + autism,
                  weights = n,
                  data = d1, family = "binomial")


## Those specifications work fine with glm and glmer

fit1_lmer <- glmer(cbind(y1, n - y1) ~
                  age + gender + emotional + autism +
                  (1 | cluster_id), data = d1, family = "binomial")

fit2_lmer <- glmer(p1 ~
                  age + gender + emotional + autism + 
                  (1 | cluster_id), data = d1, family = "binomial",
               weights = n)

fit1_glm <- glm(cbind(y1, n - y1) ~
                age + gender + emotional + autism,
            data = d1, family = "binomial")

fit2_glm <- glm(p1 ~
                 age + gender + emotional + autism,
             data = d1, family = "binomial",
               weights = n)
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default data preprocessing fails in the matrix case because this is handled by `mob()` (the engine underlying `glmtree()`) and this doesn't detect this automatically. But if you declare that the response is a matrix by setting `ytype = "matrix"` then it seems to work. I'll check whether it would be possible to detect that case automatically without too much hassle.

```
fit1 <- glmertree(cbind(y1, n - y1) ~ 1 | cluster_id | age + gender +
+  emotional + autism, data = d1, family = "binomial", ytype = "matrix")
fit1
## Generalized linear mixed model tree
## 
## Model formula:
## cbind(y1, n - y1) ~ 1 | age + gender + emotional + autism
## 
## Fitted party:
## [1] root
## |   [2] gender in female
## |   |   [3] age <= 8.6: n = 34
## |   |       (Intercept) 
## |   |          0.341235 
## |   |   [4] age > 8.6: n = 128
## |   |       (Intercept) 
## |   |        -0.1816504 
## |   [5] gender in male
## |   |   [6] emotional in no: n = 78
## |   |       (Intercept) 
## |   |       -0.08595909 
## |   |   [7] emotional in yes
## |   |   |   [8] autism in no: n = 101
## |   |   |       (Intercept) 
## |   |   |        -0.3942751 
## |   |   |   [9] autism in yes: n = 9
## |   |   |       (Intercept) 
## |   |   |        0.09794292 
## 
## Number of inner nodes:    4
## Number of terminal nodes: 5
## Number of parameters per node: 1
## Objective function (negative log-likelihood): 1206.711
## 
## Random effects:
## $cluster_id
##    (Intercept)
## 1   0.15831195
## 2  -0.16475415
## 3   0.32352386
## 4   0.05030959
## 5   0.27474800
## 6  -0.17771051
## 7   0.07297863
## 8   0.03953489
## 9  -0.03078364
## 10 -0.32591963
## 11  0.03101881
## 12 -0.28670007
## 13  0.03737794
## 
## with conditional variances for "cluster_id"
```

Comment: That solves the issue. Thanks. (I apologize for missing `ytype`). Could this type of response and modeling scenario be mentioned more prominently in the help or vignette itself? `ytype` might be easy to miss, as it is an argument to `mob_control` (which I did not look into, as I thought it only controlled the working of the fitting algorithm, not the model specification).  This might be simpler than automatic detection of this case.

Comment: Ramon, please also accept the answer so that the question is flagged accordingly here on SE. Also, no need to apologize! This is not obvious at all and should either be detected automatically or properly documented for `glmertree` - I completely agree. Will discuss it with Marjolein, thanks for raising this issue.